# How to search for a name in a list and remove it with a method in oop - python

Tags: python, list, oop, methods, instance

I wrote a program with which you can manage the employees of a company. I save all my objects that I create in my list `self .__ staffs = []`. Yes, I know that this is a private attribute and so do everyone else in my program, but that was the default. If I now create my instances of the classes and save them in the list `self .__ staffs = []` using the add_staff method, how can I define a method where I can find the name of the worker and whether he is a Worker, Secretary or Manager and delete it from my list? I've already tried it with `.remove(name)`, but here it only removes the instance of the Staff class, without the data on whether he is a worker, .. or not. You should look for the staff object from the `self .__ staffs` attribute by name and then remove it.Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Here is my Code:

```
class StaffList:
    def __init__(self, date: str):
        self.__date = date
        self.__staffs = []

    def get_count(self):
        t = len(self.__staffs)
        for staff in self.__staffs:    
            t -= 0.5
        return int(t) 

    def add_staff(self, staff):
        self.__staffs.append(staff)

    def remove_by_name(self, name):
        self.__staffs.remove(name)

    def __str__(self):
        a = "Date: {}\nThere are {} Staff-Member(s):\n".format(self.__date, self.get_count())
        for i in self.__staffs:
            a += i.__str__()
        return a


class Staff:
    def __init__(self, name: str, salary: int):
        self.__name = name
        self.__salary = salary

    def __str__(self):
        return "    -Members Name and Salary: {} [{}€]\n".format(self.__name, self.__salary)


class Manager(Staff):
    def __init__(self, name, salary, department: str):
        super().__init__(name, salary)
        self.__department = department

    def __str__(self):
        return "        This Member is a Manager and works in the {} department\n".format(self.__department)


class Secretary(Staff):
    def __init__(self, name, salary, has_printer: bool):
        super().__init__(name, salary)
        self.__has_printer = has_printer

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__has_printer is True:
            return "        This Member is a Secretary and has a Printer\n"
        else:
            return "        This Member is a Secretary and has no Printer\n"
    

class Worker(Staff):
    def __init__(self, name, salary, has_driving_licence: bool):
        super().__init__(name, salary)
        self.__has_driving_licence = has_driving_licence

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__has_driving_licence is True:
            return "        This Member is a Worker and has a driving licence\n"
        else:
            return "        This Member is a Wroker and has no driving licence\n"


datum = StaffList("22.11.2020")

staff1 = Staff("Josep Lanington", 2500)
datum.add_staff(staff1)
manager1 = Manager(staff1, staff1, "Elektronics")
datum.add_staff(manager1)

staff2 = Staff("Elena Kromberger", 1800)
datum.add_staff(staff2)
secretary1 = Secretary(staff2, staff2, True)
datum.add_staff(secretary1)

staff3 = Staff("Peter Angerer", 1500)
datum.add_staff(staff3)
worker1 = Worker(staff3, staff3, False)
datum.add_staff(worker1)

print(datum)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `get_count` method is wrong. Should be

```
def get_count(self):
    return len(self.__staffs)
```

you are doing something really strange here:

```
manager1 = Manager(staff1, staff1, "Elektronics")
datum.add_staff(manager1)
```

You created an instance of class Manager, giving another instance of class as name and salary.

I guess what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
staff1 = Manager("Josep Lanington", 2500, "Elektronics")
datum.add_staff(staff1)

staff2 = Secretary("Elena Kromberger", 1800, True)
datum.add_staff(staff2)

staff3 = Worker("Peter Angerer", 1500, False)
datum.add_staff(staff3)

print(datum)
```

Now, in order to remove an item from a list with .remove() method you should be able to compare this item to .remove() parameter.
But your class don't know how to compare parameter with a string.
You could add this method to your Staff() class.

```
def __eq__(self, name):
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        # don't attempt to compare against unrelated types
        return NotImplemented
    return self.__name == name
```

Now you can do `datum.remove_by_name("Elena Kromberger")`.
This is not very elegant (since you define method `__eq__` to work against string) but this might give you an idea how to move forward.

Another thing to consider is that if there is no Staff member with such name you would get an error

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list